# What's the difference between null and ()=>null?

Tags: dart, null, closures

I am new to dart and puzzled with null_closures.

For example:

```
void _test1({VoidCallback callback}) {
  callback();
}
```

Would crash when I used as:

```
_test1(callback: null);
```

But work well as:

```
_test1(callback: () => null);
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dart
_test1(callback: null);
```

In this case, `callback` is `null`.  Attempting to dereference `null` by accessing properties (with some exceptions) or by calling methods on it will result in an exception. (In most other languages, this would be a null pointer exception.  In Dart, `null` is a special object (of type `Null`), so attempting to call methods on it instead usually will throw a `NoSuchMethod` error.)

```dart
_test1(callback: () => null);
```

In this case, `callback` is a *function* (an object of type `Function`) that *returns* `null` when that function is invoked.